# Use Yii CDbCriteria to get dates with a specific month

Tags: php, yii

Hi i'd like to know if there is anyway we can use CDbCriteria to get data based on dates with a specific month. Say i need all entries that were created in May, i have a column `paid_on` so when i select May(05), i need to get all entries xxxx-05-xx that have 05 as month. I got this with Yii create db command

```
$monthno = date('m',strtotime($_POST['month']));
$sql     = "SELECT * FROM fee_track WHERE DATE_FORMAT(paid_on,'%m') = ".$monthno."";
$data    = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

I need to know if i can do the same with CDbCriteria. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `condition` with `CDbCriteria()` like this, it should work for you.

```
$monthno = date('m',strtotime($_POST['month']));

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select="*";
$criteria->condition = "DATE_FORMAT(paid_on,'%m')=:monthno";
$criteria->params = array(':monthno'=>$monthno);
$modelResult= Yii::app()->db->commandBuilder->createFindCommand(fee_track,$criteria)->findAll();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($model);
echo '</pre>';
```

EDIT: As Per Comment

```
$modelResult= YourModel::model()-
 >findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Hi thanks a bunch it worked, but $modelresult dint need Yii::app()->db... i just used a normal $model= MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);

Comment: @Arun , Yes $model= MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria); is also good one.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "DATE_FORMAT(paid_on,'%m')=:monthno";
$criteria->params = array(':monthno'=>'05');
$model= YourModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

I Think this will help you :)

Comment: Hi this dint work, but the code posted below by Being Sunny helped. Thanks a lot anyways!! :)